# Bootstrap layout design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to setup a column layout in the following way.  On "md" and bigger devices I have 2 columns md-8 and md-4.  However on smaller devices I actually want to show 1/2 of the content in the md-8 column, THEN half of the md-4 column then the rest of the md-8 column... Hopefully the attached picture helps.

[image]

So on a mobile device I want to see, A,B,C,D stacked on each other in that order.  The problem I have is A and B are variable heights, and no matter what I try I end up with gaps of space either between A & C or B & D.  Any thoughts on what my layout should be?

Comment: If A is taller on desktop would you want B to be the same height?

Comment: No, on desktops I want A & C and B & D to look like individual columns.

Comment: You might have to have two containers. One for desktop and one for mobile if that's acceptable?  One desktop you would have two columns ordered a|c and b|d and then on mobile you would have one column ordered A|B|C|D

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, if I understand well, you want to split to halfs by vertical, isn't it?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">A1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">B1</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">A2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">B2</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">C</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">D</div>
</div>
```

Edited, ty fot warning.

Comment: Please post the _code_ as an answer with a link as a supplement. Answers shouldn't consist of solely external links.

Comment: This isn't doing what I was hoping for, if you change your code to have more content in B1:  

`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">A1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">B1<br/>B1<br/>B1<br/>B1<br/>B1<br/></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">A2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">B2</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">C</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">D</div>
</div>`

Then there is space between A1 and A2.